# Rails query has_and_belongs_to_many with exact count

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-5

I have the following setup

```
class Cake
  has_and_belongs_to_many :ingredients # through a join table 
end

class Ingredient
 # secret_id , optional integer column. 
end
```

I receive a handful of secret ids.
I want to generate a query that returns Cakes, only if I can get all the ingredients.

```
Cake A: 
  Ingredient A -> secret id -> 1
  Ingredient B -> secret id -> nil

Cake B: 
  Ingredient C -> secret id -> 3
  Ingredient D -> secret id -> nil
```

Let's say we get a request with the following params: `[3,4,5]`
My current query looks like this

```
Cake.includes(:ingredients).where(ingredients: { secret_id: secret_id_params + [nil] })
```

The problem with this, it will return both Cake A & Cake B.
It returns Cake A because it has a nil secret id in one of it's ingredients.
I don't want to return Cake A, because I didn't find all the ingredients.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you just need to have something like this

```
  Cake.includes(:ingredients).where 
   ingredients: { secret_id: secret_id_params + 
      [nil] } and count(ingredients) = Ingredients.(
         count(distinct secretid) )
```